# What is Vue's property for accessing a computed property?

Tags: vue.js

How to get a value of a Vue's computed property (**but without using a shortcut**), so, if you have an instance of a VueComponent class, how would you do it?

For more context, suppose you have a data variable named `v` and a computed property named `v`. Sure, you can access both of them when only one of them is defined by using `this.v`.

But, this is because Vue enables shortcut for accessing it inside a component, but they are not really defined there. What is the full path, lets call it like that, for a computed property?

To get you to understand what I want, let me answer the question for a data property.
For example, `v` data property can be accessed on any of the three ways:

1. `this.v`
2. `this.$data.v`
3. `this._data.v`

`this._data.v` is, let us call it, 'the full path' to the `v` data variable. That is where the variable is actually stored in a Vue component.

My question is where is the computed property stored? What would be 'the full path' to the `v` computed property?

`this._computed` is `null` so I know it is more complicated than that.

(If you must know why I ask this, it is because I have both data property and computed property with the same name. And yes, of course I know that they should have different names, but the point of this question is not the best practice but rather Vue's theory, tips and tricks of how to have both data and computed property with the same name).

Comment: Provided you already know that computed property is actually just a function, and say `vm` is your instance variable, and you are not using composition api, you can access it via `vm._computedWatchers.propertyName.get()` where `propertyName` is the name of computed property you want to access.

Comment: Thank you, that is where it is...; please put this into an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: There is no public property with such purpose. The said usage is not documented and may fail you any moment. Digging into internals may help you for debugging or other off-label usage but it's a bad practice to have name collisions, not just not the best one. They result in framework warnings at least.